# What to do if no /dev/dsp or /dev/audio or /dev/MAKE

Tags: audio

I am using Fedora 20, with Mate desktop and `zshell`.

In order to  practice reading Morse code, I want to play text as Morse using a program `cwcpm` downloaded from [this site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cwtext/?source=typ_redirect). The documentation with it suggests the test command `cwtext "cheers" | /dev/audio`, but this give me the error message `zsh: no such file or directory: /dev/audio`. Same thing for `/dev/dsp`

I have no trouble with getting audio when I play films, YouTube videos or BBC i-player programmes.

Please what should I do to get this program working?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, it is to use the built-in pulse audio package. I will edit this answer to give more details later.